# How to force JCombox to be in a selected state

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How would I programatically set the state of a `JComboBox` to be selected and show its content in the drop down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the selected index using: `setSelectedItem(Object item)` or `setSelectedIndex(int index)` then call on your `JComboBox` instance:

```
jComboBox.showPopup();
//or
//jComboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
```

If you'd like it to be visible for a certain period of time only just use a Swing `Timer` to call `setPopupVisible(false);` after a certain period of time has elapsed.

**References**:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, when Java Doc say **"This method is public but should not be called by anything other than the UI delegate."**, does that mean, we can make an explicit call to `firePopupMenuWillBecomeVisible()` in our code ?

Comment: @GagandeepBali Ah I see reading the fine print now. Lol as always you're correct :)